# Finding an element in an array where every element is repeated odd number of times (but more than single occurrence) and only one appears once

Tags: arrays, algorithm

You have an array in which every number is repeated odd number of times (but more than single occurrence). Exactly one number appears once. How do you find the number that appears only once?

```
e.g.: {1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

The answer is 9.

I was thinking about having a hash table and then just counting the element whose count is 1.
This seems trivial and i am not using the fact that every other element is repeated an odd no of times. Is there a better approach.

Comment: If 9 is really the answer, that's not a very good phrasing of the question.  I'd argue that 9 appears an odd number of times (1 time) as does 1 (3 times), 3(5 times) and 6(3 times).  A more interesting question is where some repeat an odd number of times and some repeat an even number of times.

Comment: sorry about my misreading.  could some of the question be missing?  perhaps the idea is that you have to use fixed size of memory?  but that still doesn't make it very interesting, and doesn't use "odd", as far as i can see.

Comment: Here's a link to the more interesting versino in which there are odd and even repeats: http://www.technicalinterviewquestions.net/2009/01/integer-array-odd-even-occurrences-find.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe you can still use the basic idea of XOR to solve this problem in a clever fashion.

First, let's change the problem so that one number appears once and all other numbers appear three times.

---

***Algorithm:***

Here `A` is the array of length `n`:

```
   int ones = 0;  
   int twos = 0;  
   int not_threes, x;  

   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {  
            x =  A[i];  
            twos |= ones & x;  
            ones ^= x;  
            not_threes = ~(ones & twos);  
            ones &= not_threes;  
            twos &= not_threes;  
   }
```

And the element that occurs precisely once is stored in `ones`. This uses `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

I believe I can extend this idea to the general case of the problem, but possibly one of you can do it faster, so I'll leave this for now and edit it when and if I can generalize the solution.

---

***Explanation:***

If the problem were this: "one element appears once, all others an even number of times", then the solution would be to XOR the elements. The reason is that `x^x = 0`, so all the paired elements would vanish leaving only the lonely element. If we tried the same tactic here, we would be left with the XOR of distinct elements, which is not what we want.

Instead, the algorithm above does the following:

- `ones` is the XOR of all elements that have appeared exactly once so far
- `twos` is the XOR of all elements that have appeared exactly twice so far

Each time we take `x` to be the next element in the array, there are three cases:

1. if this is the first time `x` has appeared, it is XORed into `ones`
2. if this is the second time `x` has appeared, it is taken out of `ones` (by XORing it again) and XORed into `twos`
3. if this is the third time `x` has appeared, it is taken out of `ones` and `twos`.

Therefore, in the end, `ones` will be the XOR of just one element, the lonely element that is not repeated. There are 5 lines of code that we need to look at to see why this works: the five after `x = A[i]`.

If this is the first time `x` has appeared, then `ones&x=ones` so `twos` remains unchanged. The line `ones ^= x;` XORs `x` with `ones` as claimed. Therefore `x` is in exactly one of `ones` and `twos`, so nothing happens in the last three lines to either `ones` or `twos`.

If this is the second time `x` has appeared, then `ones` already has `x` (by the explanation above), so now `twos` gets it with the line `twos |= ones & x;`. Also, since `ones` has `x`, the line `ones ^= x;` removes `x` from `ones` (because `x^x=0`). Once again, the last three lines do nothing since exactly one of `ones` and `twos` now has `x`.

If this is the third time `x` has appeared, then `ones` does not have `x` but `twos` does. So the first line let's `twos` keep `x` and the second adds `x` to `ones`. Now, since both `ones` and `twos` have `x`, the last three lines remove `x` from both.

---

***Generalization:***

If some numbers appear 5 times, then this algorithm still works. This is because the 4th time `x` appears, it is in neither `ones` nor `twos`. The first two lines then add `x` to `ones` and not `twos` and the last three lines do nothing. The 5th time `x` appears, it is in `ones` but not `twos`. The first line adds it to `twos`, the second removed it from `ones`, and the last three lines do nothing.

The problem is that the 6th time `x` appears, it is taken from `ones` and `twos`, so it gets added back to `ones` on the 7th pass. I'm trying to think of a clever way to prevent this, but so far I'm coming up empty.

Comment: @Luchian: Same time, not same space. In any event, at least I'm using the oddness of the problem :-)

Comment: @Tom Zych - I downvoted everyone with more than 100 reputation who gave a bad answer.

Comment: @Tom: Based on the comments, probably Luchian. And the downvotes weren't wholly unjustified on most of the answers.

Comment: Uh huh, well, what do you call an answer that's virtually impossible to understand or tell whether it's correct, then? A good answer?

Comment: @Tom: You can run the code. I just did. It works. I generally don't explain things adequately (a flaw I'm working on), so I'll try to write an explanation for this. Feel free to vote my answer down, though, if you feel it isn't useful or correct.

Comment: @Tom Zych - this is already a million times better than the other answers for the simple fact that it doesn't suggest the same solution the OP has, or even worse. If I find that it doesn't work or @PengOne doesn't detail it, then I will downvote this as well, but I think it deserves a chance. @PengOne - how would you turn the initial problem into the one you are solving in `O(1)` space?

Comment: Well, it looks like I might have to downvote :). I am getting 0 for the input `1 2 1 1`

Comment: Works for your constrained case. But just like the first person who suggested XOR for even numbers, this doesn't answer the question stated. I'm looking forward to the generalized case edit (if one exists).

Comment: I like your solution so far; for generalizing it consider NOT removing x from from ones and twos. Then, at the end of your function, ones holds values that have appeared 1 or more times, while twos holds values that have appeared 2 or more times. XOR them together and viola. I'll admit, I'm not certain this works.

Comment: @IVlad: Are you certain you've implemented it correctly? My implementation (in C) produces the output `2` for the input `{1,2,1,1}`.

Comment: @Bob: good idea. That way I track what has occurred at least two times and what has occurred an odd number of times. I believe it works if I pull the last three lines out of the `for` loop. I'll think on it a bit. Feel free to post your own version so I can vote it up. Great suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the return. +1.

Comment: I'm getting the correct output for {1, 2, 1, 1}, but I'm getting 2 for {1, 3, 1, 1}.  I don't see how this can work.

Comment: @recursive: Yes, the generalization seemed to have some issues... I've rolled back to the last time the code worked. I think Bob's idea should work to get the generalization, but I also think I've spent enough time on this problem for now.

Comment: It's not possible to generalize this solution.  See my answer for both an explanation of why and a clearer explanation of what the code in this answer is doing.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please explain "If this is the first time x has appeared, then ones&x=ones so twos remains unchanged. ". Suppose ones=23, only one element has been so far, x=25, then ones&x =17. I am definitely doing some mistake. Could you please correct me or point out?

Comment: I think the last three lines of the first algorithm deserve some more explanation. It's not really a simple matter of removing the triple number from the sets, right? After all, imagine the sequence [2, 2, 3, 2]. When the 3 is reached, ones = 0011 and twos = 0010. However, ones & twos = 0010 (2), so the second bit is turned off in both ones and twos even though a triple hasn't been detected yet. This results in ones = 0001 and twos = 0000. When the last element, the third 2, is reached, it's not in twos (since it's 0000) and so gets added to ones, becoming 0011. This isn't how it's described.

Comment: Note: "If the problem were this: "one element appears once, all others an even number of times"" <-- can be changed to   "one element appears an odd number of times, all others an even number of times" without affecting the logic of the program.

Answer (score 21):

For the problem as stated it is most likely that the most efficient answer is the O(n) space answer.  On the other hand, if we narrow the problem to be "All numbers appear n times except for one which only appears once" or even "All numbers appear a multiple of n times except for one which only appears once" then there's a fairly straightforward solution for any n (greater than 1, obviously) which takes only O(1) space, which is to break each number into bits and then count how many times each bit is turned on and take that modulo n.  If the result is 1, then it should be turned on in the answer.  If it is 0, then it should be turned off.  (Any other answer shows that the parameters of the problem did not hold).  If we examine the situation where n is 2, we can see that using XOR does exactly this (bitwise addition modulo 2).  We're just generalizing things to do bitwise addition modulo n for other values of n.

This, by the way, is what the other answer for n=3 does, it's actually just a complex way of doing bit-wise addition where it stores a 2-bit count for each bit.  The int called "ones" contains the ones bit of the count and the int called "twos" contains the twos bit of the count.  The int not_threes is used to set both bits back to zero when the count reaches 3, thus counting the bits modulo 3 rather than normally (which would be modulo 4 since the bits would wrap around).  The easiest way to understand his code is as a 2-bit accumulator with an extra part to make it work modulo 3.

So, for the case of all numbers appearing a multiple of 3 times except the one unique number, we can write the following code for 32 bit integers:

```
int findUnique(int A[], int size) {
  // First we set up a bit vector and initialize it to 0.
  int count[32];
  for (int j=0;j<32;j++) {
    count[j] = 0;
  }

  // Then we go through each number in the list.
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    int x = A[i];

    // And for each number we go through its bits one by one.
    for (int j=0;j<32;j++) {
      // We add the bit to the total.
      count[j] += x & 1;
      // And then we take it modulo 3.
      count[j] %= 3;
      x >>= 1;
    }
  }

  // Then we just have to reassemble the answer by putting together any
  // bits which didn't appear a multiple of 3 times.
  int answer = 0;
  for (int j=31;j>=0;j--) {
    answer <<= 1;
    if (count[j] == 1) {
      answer |= 1;
    }
  }

  return answer;
}
```

This code is slightly longer than the other answer (and superficially looks more complex due to the additional loops, but they're each constant time), but is hopefully easier to understand.  Obviously, we could decrease the memory space by packing the bits more densely since we never use more than two of them for any number in count.  But I haven't bothered to do that since it has no effect on the asymptotic complexity.

If we wish to change the parameters of the problem so that instead the numbers are repeated 5 times, we just change the 3s to 5s.  Or we can do likewise for 7, 11, 137, 727, or any other number (including even numbers).  But instead of using the actual number, we can use any factor of it, so for 9, we could just leave it as 3, and for even numbers we can just use 2 (and hence just use xor).

However, there is no general bit-counting based solution for the original problem where a number can be repeated any odd number of times.  This is because even if we count the bits exactly without using modulo, when we look at a particular bit, we simply can't know whether the 9 times it appears represents 3 + 3 + 3 or 1 + 3 + 5.  If it was turned on in three different numbers which each appeared three times, then it should be turned off in our answer.  If it was turned on in a number which appeared once, a number which appeared three times, and a number which appeared five times, then it should be turned on in our answer.  But with just the count of the bits, it's impossible for us to know this.

This is why the other answer doesn't generalize and the clever idea to handle the special cases is not going to materialize: any scheme based on looking at things bit by bit to figure out which bits should be turned on or off does not generalize.  Given this, I don't think that any scheme which takes space O(1) works for the general case.  It is possible that there are clever schemes which use O(lg n) space or so forth, but I would doubt it.  I think that the O(n) space approach is probably the best which can be done in the problem as proposed.  I can't prove it, but at this point, it's what my gut tells me and I hope that I've at least convinced you that small tweaks to the "even number" technique are not going to cut it.

Comment: I have question relating to your code.If the array was {1,2,2,2}, the count[] after going through each number would contain: 1,0,0..(0 will be 31 times)-if I understand correctly,count[0] is recording whether LSB has been set 1,or 3 times.So when we get to the last for loop, count[0] = 1,so answer is bitwise OR with 1,which would make answer = 00..(31 times)1.My question is that then you left shift answer,and proceed in the for loop,so in the end,answer would be: 100..(31 times),wouldn't this be the reverse of the answer? I was expecting 00..(31 times)1 (for 1).Please correct if wrong, thanks.

Comment: Actually, you won't even get that.  You'd just get 00..(32 times) because I accidentally shifted the 1 from the front away during the last iteration of the loop when the shift happened after the or.  But yeah, it was definitely reversing things.  Sorry about that.  That's what I get for writing code without testing it.  It had a couple of other mistakes in the first loop which was supposed to initialize everything to 0 as well.  So, all fixed now.  Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the subtext of this question is to find an efficient or performant solution, but I think that the simplest, readable code counts for a lot and in most cases it is more than sufficient.

So how about this:

```
var value = (new [] { 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, })
    .ToLookup(x => x)
    .Where(xs => xs.Count() == 1)
    .First()
    .Key;
```

Good old LINQ. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Test Score 100% with c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// you can also use other imports, for example:
// using System.Collections.Generic;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// Console.WriteLine("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        Dictionary<int, int> dic =new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach(int i in A)
        {
            if (dic.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                dic[i]=dic[i]+1;                
            }
            else
            {
                dic.Add(i, 1);                
            }
        }

        foreach(var d in dic)
        {
            if (d.Value%2==1)
            {
                 return d.Key;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java, Correctness 100%, Performance 100%, Task score 100%

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");
import java.util.HashMap;

class Solution {

     /*Simple solution 
          Will be using HashMap(for performance) as Array, 
          only Key set is needed.
          Initially tried with ArryList but there was performance issue with
          that so switch to HashMap.
          Iterate over the given array and if item is there in key set         
          remove it(coz you found your pair) otherwise add as new Key.
          After full Iteration only one key will be there in the Map that is 
          your solution.
          In Short: If pair is found, remove it from Map's Key set,
          Last Key will be your solution
    */
    public int solution(int[] A) {

        //Map but used as Array
        final HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mapHave = new HashMap<>();

        //Iterate over given Array
        for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < A.length; nIdx++) {

            //Current Item
            Integer nVal = A[nIdx];

            //Try to remove the current item, if item does not exists will
            //return null and if condition will be true
            if (mapHave.remove(nVal) == null) {
                //current item not found, add it
                mapHave.put(nVal, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
        }

        //There will be only one key remaining in the Map, that is
        //your solution
        return mapHave.keySet().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla yes, thank you for pointing it out. i am modifying the solution with comments. please revert back if you feel some changes are needed.

Comment: this is not O(n) since it uses a hashtable that is O(log(n))