# Find the Element Occurring b times in an an array of size n*k+b

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**Description**

Given an Array of size `(n*k+b)` where n elements occur k times and one element occurs b times, in other words there are `n+1` distinct Elements. Given that `0 < b < k` find the element occurring b times.

**My Attempted solutions**

1. Obvious solution will be using hashing but it will not work if the numbers are very large. Complexity is `O(n)`
2. Using map to store the frequencies of each element and then traversing map to find the element occurring b times.As Map's are implemented as height balanced trees Complexity will be `O(nlogn)`.

Both of my solution were accepted but the interviewer wanted a linear solution without using hashing and hint he gave was make the height of tree constant in tree in which you are storing frequencies, but I am not able to figure out the correct solution yet.

I want to know how to solve this problem in linear time without hashing?

EDIT:

Sample:

Input: `n=2 b=2 k=3`

Aarray: `2 2 2 3 3 3 1 1`

Output: `1`

Comment: Note that your solution is `O((n*k+b)logn)`, and not `O(nlogn)` - given the terms of the question.

Comment: Can you give an sample array holding sample values?

Comment: I suspect the interviewer wanted to hear something like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). But that's plain stupid. The height of the trie is at least as large as `O(logn)`, so if you can say it is a "constant" - so does `O(logn)`

Comment: Are you sure about what the interviewer meant? Such as any hints on the range of elements? If they range from [0..n-1] solution is obvious.

Comment: yes i'm sure....i confirmed that time only....number are random not necessarily between 1 to n.

Comment: Very similar question: [Finding an element in an array that isn't repeated a multiple of three times?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7338437/1009831).

Comment: From your sample (2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1) it **looks** like the elements are grouped together. This is not the case, right? I mean, it could be e.g. (1,2,3,3,1,2,2,3)?

Comment: yes...they may or may not be grouped together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An idea using cyclic groups.

To guess i-th bit of answer, follow this procedure:

1. Count how many numbers in array has i-th bit set, store as `cnt`
2. If `cnt % k` is non-zero, then i-th bit of answer is set. Otherwise it is clear.

To guess whole number, repeat the above for every bit.

This solution is technically `O((n*k+b)*log max N)`, where `max N` is maximal value in the table, but because number of bits is usually constant, this solution is linear in array size.

No hashing, memory usage is `O(log k * log max N)`.

Example implementation:

```
from random import randint, shuffle

def generate_test_data(n, k, b):
    k_rep = [randint(0, 1000) for i in xrange(n)]
    b_rep = [randint(0, 1000)]
    numbers = k_rep*k + b_rep*b
    shuffle(numbers)
    print "k_rep: ", k_rep
    print "b_rep: ", b_rep
    return numbers

def solve(data, k):
    cnts = [0]*10
    for number in data:
        bits = [number >> b & 1 for b in xrange(10)]
        cnts = [cnts[i] + bits[i] for i in xrange(10)]
    return reduce(lambda a,b:2*a+(b%k>0), reversed(cnts), 0)

print "Answer: ", solve(generate_test_data(10, 15, 13), 3)
```

Comment: Except for the ``*log(max(N))`` issue (which as point, may or may not be within the problem constraints), I like your solution better than mine.

Comment: @Ali, well, technically all arithmetic operations are `O(log max N)`, it's just usually we limit ourselves to a fixed number of bits. So your solution isn't free from that factor too. My algorithm just makes it explicit.

Comment: Won't this fail if b % k = 0 ?

Comment: @rajatkhanduja: see the first paragraph of the question: 0 < b < k. Yes, it will fail in your case. This assumption is what actually allows this problem to be computed so quickly in so little memory.

Answer (score 11):

I assume:

1. The elements of the array are comparable.
2. We know the values of n and k beforehand.
3. A solution O(n*k+b) is good enough.

Let the number occuring only b times be S. We are trying to find the S in an array of n*k+b size.

**Recursive Step:** Find the median element of the current array slice as in Quick Sort in lineer time. Let the median element be M.

After the recursive step you have an array where all elements smaller than M occur on the left of the first occurence of M. All M elements are next to each other and all element larger than M are on the right of all occurences of M.

Look at the index of the leftmost M and calculate whether S<M or S>=M. Recurse either on the left slice or the right slice.

So you are doing a quick sort but delving only one part of the divisions at any time. You will recurse O(logN) times but each time with 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, .. sizes of the original array, so the total time will still be O(n).

**Clarification:** Let's say n=20 and k = 10. Then, there are 21 distinct elements in the array, 20 of which occur 10 times and the last occur let's say 7 times. I find the medium element, let's say it is 1111. If the S<1111 than the index of the leftmost occurence of 1111 will be less than 11*10. If S>=1111 then the index will be equal to 11*10.

**Full example:** n = 4. k = 3. Array = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,5} 
After the first recursive step I find the median element is 3 and the array is something like: {1,2,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,5,4,5,5,4} There are 6 elements on the left of 3. 6 is a multiple of k=3. So each element must be occuring 3 times there. So S>=3. Recurse on the right side. And so on.

Comment: I don't get how can you decide if you want to recurse on the left or on the right. the value `S` is unkown, how can you compare `S==M`? Could you clarify these points please?

Comment: I added a clarification and an example.

Comment: the clarification doesn't clarify anything. you only provide the main point of your algorithm in the full example. you also don't check the *pivot value*. total time is o(N) *average*, it's a randomized algorithm.

Comment: There is a **deterministic** lineer time algorithm to find the median in an array. See the relevant section on Cormen's book or check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm   Yes, I don't provide all the details and a working code because it is unnecessary, it can be done with successive selection of medians and it should be good enough for an interview answer. Is there anything else that needs clarification?

Comment: @yi_H: [there are `O(N)`, worst-case linear time, selection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) (in particular for finding a median element) therefore the algorithm in the answer is also worst-case linear time ([`T(N) = T(N/2) +  N`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28N%29%20%3D%20T%28N%2F2%29%20%2B%20N): `N` - to find median, `T(N/2)` - recursive step).

Comment: in the example you missed writing 5 in the array after finding median

Comment: would this one be faster than converting the array to a set?

Comment: @deathApril no, it would not be faster. But using hash is forbidden, and how can one implement a set without hashing? Even the elements don't have to be integers, they could be of any type.

Comment: +1 @Ali you are right about the hashing of course,, but please don't confuse numbers with integers or assume that strings or objects can't be manipulated as numbers

Answer (score 4):

In order to have a constant height *B-tree* containing `n` distinct elements, with height `h` constant, you need `z=n^(1/h)` children per nodes: `h=log_z(n)`, thus `h=log(n)/log(z)`, thus `log(z)=log(n)/h`, thus `z=e^(log(n)/h)`, thus `z=n^(1/h)`.

Example, with `n=1000000`, `h=10`, `z=3.98`, that is `z=4`.

The time to reach a node in that case is `O(h.log(z))`. Assuming `h` and `z` to be "constant" (since `N=n.k`, then `log(z)=log(n^(1/h))=log(N/k^(1/h))=ct` by properly choosing `h` based on `k`, you can then say that `O(h.log(z))=O(1)`... This is a bit far-fetched, but maybe that was the kind of thing the interviewer wanted to hear?

Comment: And how does he generate the table [without hash] in this complexity?

Comment: Which table? If you talk about the frequency table, I assume you know `n` beforehand -- if you don't, you can use a map. For the elements table, it's given as an input.

Comment: Finding the frequencies table requires a `map`, which is implemented as a tree [hash is not allowed]. each OP on a tree is `O(logn)`

Comment: creating a table without will take O((n*k+b)logn) as during creation you have to traverse the array and increase the frequency at the proper place which will take O(log n) with height balanced tree.

Comment: You're right, I misread one critical point in the question, no hashing is permitted.

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE**: this one use hashing, so it's not a good answer :(*

in python this would be linear time (`set` will remove the duplicates):

```
result = (sum(set(arr))*k - sum(arr)) / (k - b)
```

Comment: i think result should be divided by `k-b` to obtain the required number bcoz number is k times in first sum and b times in second sum.

Comment: and how you can be sure it will be linear ?? ......is set function in python linear ?

Comment: Interesting solution but it has two problems. First, Python most probably uses hashing in its set implementation so using a set would be cheating. Second it works only when the array elements are integers, that is not told in the question, they could be i.e. strings.

Comment: @Amol Sharma: [set() in Python is linear](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) but it uses hashing.

Comment: @Ali yes, i forgot about the hashing - removing duplicates without hashing wouldn't be very fast i guess :(( but i read in one comment that `number are random not necessarily between 1 to n` so i assumed they are numbers...

Comment: @Ali and since when anything on a computer is not a number? `01111000 01101111 01111000 01101111` :))

Answer (score 0):

If 'k' is even and 'b' is odd, then XOR will do. :)