# finding time complexity of searching in following array

Tags: algorithm, analysis

there is a sorted array which is of very large size.In those elements every element is repeated more than once except one element.What is the worst time complexity of the best algorithm to solve this problem and also give that algorithm

Comment: This looks like homework, so I'll answer a different question. If the array was not sorted and the elements were repeated an even number of times while one element appeared an odd number, your best shot would be O(n).  Still I won't tell you the algorithm. It's a trick... When the array is sorted, can you do better? (This was answered by @smanohar).  What can you do if you know nothing about odd/even?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if a number only apears once in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569670/determine-if-a-number-only-apears-once-in-an-array)

Comment: @nickie if you look at the possible duplicate I posted, is your answer similar to that?  I am having a hard time coming up with how the array being sorted helps.

Comment: I didn't say it does help, I said, does it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be log(n).

Given: The sorted array, all the elements except one is repeated. Then till that single element the index of elements will occupy even and next odd number. After this single element, they will occupy odd and next even index.

With this logic start the binary search.

```
bsearch (a, low, high)  
    mid = (low + high)/2  
    if ((a[mid-1] != a[mid]) && (a[mid+1] != a[mid]))  
          return a[mid]
    else
       mid = (mid & ~0x1) //making mid an even index
       if (a[mid] == a[mid+1]) //single element is after this index
                 bsearch (a, mid + 2, high)
       else //element is before this
                 bsearch (a, low, mid-1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think it says "repeated more than once", not "repeated exactly twice" or "repeated an even number of times"...

Comment: Yes @nickie. Thanks for pointing out. I missed that :-(. If that is so then the algorithm could be implemented with the hashtables to keep it O(n).